# How to stop knockout.js bindings evaluating on child elements

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, element

Using knockout, when you call `ko.applyBinding(viewModel, "divId")` it does a recursive binding down through the children of the element you bound to ("divId"). I would like to stop this evaluation at a child node. Is there a way to do this?

the reason why...

I would like to bind the entire page to a navigation view model, this will handle basic layout and ...smile... navigation. On the various pages I would like to bind certain regions to different view models that are not properties of the navigation view model. At the moment if I do this I get "unable to parse binding" errors as the navigation view model does not have the required properties. If I could stop the binding walking down the dom, I could just bind these items separately.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are several ways that you can go on this one.  Typically, you would add multiple "sub" view models to a main view model and then use the `with` binding on the various areas with the actual view models to bind against them.

It is possible to technically do what you are after.   You can create a custom binding that tells KO that it will handle binding the children itself.  It would look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBindings = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }  
};
```

When you place this on an element, then KO will ignore the children.  Then, you could call ko.applyBindings on a child of this element with a different view model.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tWJxh/

Typically though, you would use multiple view models underneath a main view model using the `with` binding.

Comment: Excellent stuff, exactly what I wanted. My scenario may not be typical but it gives me a true module based loading approach where each module is independent of all others, makes testing fun...

Comment: This forces the use of an extra container simply to stop the bindings; Would it be easy to make container-less (comment) nodes support custom binding handlers such as the above stopBindings ? It would be useful in highly modular apps :)

Comment: In 2.1 (in RC), container-less custom binding handlers will be possible like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/75yQD/.  So, it will be no problem.  In 2.0, `ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings` was not exposed.

Comment: I'm having trouble with controlsDescendantBindings. Why does http://jsfiddle.net/C6wXY/ not bind the child list in the foreach? When I do something similar in my code, the foreach binding is processed by the parent regardless of returning controlsDescendantBindings: true from the bindingHandler init function.

Answer (score 3):

One way I have done this is to create a section for the navigation (or just a ) and bind the navVM to it. Then create another section for the content and bind the contentVM to it. That way there is no conflict and its all very separated.

```
<body>
    <div id="navSection">
    </div>
    <div id="contentSection">
    </div>
</body>
```

Then do ko.applyBinding(navVM, "navSection") and ko.applyBinding(contentVM, "contentSection")

Comment: mmm...pity it is not easy to create two separate binding contexts that are in the same subtree

Comment: you "can" do it (see Ryan's note), i was just saying that it might be more structured to think of your components as their own loosely coupled modules.