# Knockout.js ko.applyBindings() hierarchy binding

Tags: knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/3JRVS/1/

In js console I get the error:

"Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: new_book is not defined;
Bindings value: value: new_book().name"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please look for this question. Maybe it will help You a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254632/how-to-stop-knockout-js-bindings-evaluating-on-child-elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `ko.applyBindings` with a specific element as the second parameter then it will recursively bind everything under that element.

In your case, when you call `ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById("content"));` it will bind everything under that element, which includes "books" and "about".

Some options:

1. make sure that "content" is in its own element (not an ancestor of
   books/about)
2. use a custom binding around your books/about areas to
   prevent the "content" binding from going into those elements
   (described here:
   [How to stop knockout.js bindings evaluating on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254632/how-to-stop-knockout-js-bindings-evaluating-on-child-elements))
3. add your view models to a main view model and use the `with`
   binding against your `sub` view models.

Option #3 would be my recommendation.  Here is a sample from your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8dhzK/

Comment: Thank you. You have helped me

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because this line

```
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById("content"));
```

binds the entire "content" div (including all children divs like "books" and "about") to AppViewModel that doesn't have new_book property. As AlfeG pointed out in the comment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254632/how-to-stop-knockout-js-bindings-evaluating-on-child-elements) is how you can solve the problem.