# Knockout.js ko.applyBindings() bind part of a viewmodel to a separate div

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model which I map using the knockout mapper to create observable properties from it.

```
var viewModel= {
    "Name": "Josh",
    "Position": "Developer",
    "PersonalInfo": [{
         "CashierMail": "Test@testin.com",
          "Phone": "1234",

    }]    
  }

var myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);
```

I have the following html:

```
<div>
The name is <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    <div id="info">
        Mail is <span data-bind="text: CashierMail"></span>
        <br>
        Position is <span data-bind="text: Position"></span>
        <br>
        Phone is <span data-bind="text: Phone"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my original code using only one binding from myViewModel and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/837/

What I want to accomplish is the fields in the div with id "info" to be populated with the data from Personal Info observable array. With other words if `<div id="info">` is a component - to be populated with its own datasource.

So I try something like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel.PersonalInfo[0], document.getElementById("info"));
```

But it does not work.

But I want to do the things as I described above. Here is the code that is not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/833/

I read this topic which is similar to my case but still couldn't make it work:

[Knockout.js ko.applyBindings() hierarchy binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256938/knockout-js-ko-applybindings-hierarchy-binding)

I am rather new to javascript and knockout and any help with working code will be greatly appreciated. Thank You for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access an item in an observableArray holds, then you need to access the underlying array like:

`myViewModel.PersonalInfo()[0]`

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KHFn8/844/

Comment: please help me out in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105737/dynamic-row-creation-knockout-js