# How can I apply KnockoutJS on a master page and an individual page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, webforms, master-pages

I'm stuck on an older WebForms project and I'd like to know if there's a recommended approach for my scenario.

### Goal

- I have a feedback form in a modal dialog that I bound up using KnockoutJS.
- I would like the feedback form to be available on all pages, via a link in the footer of the site.
- I would like to have several other pages using knockout as well with their own individual scripts & bindings, irrespective of the feedback form bindings in the modal.
- I have some pages that do not use knockout at all. I would like them not to have to insert code to accomplish this.
- I would like to avoid global variables, if possible, in favor of namespaced JavaScript.
- In essence, I would like for the viewmodels on the page and the feedback viewmodel not to be aware of each others' existence.

### Current Setup

- Our footer links are in a Site.master file, and so that's where I've placed the Feedback.js script and the div for the modal which has the bindings. So on the master page, I call `ko.applyBindings(vm, referenceToFeedbackDiv)`, which works fine to wire up the feedback form.
- Our individual pages occasionally have a knockout viewmodel, and so they may call ko.applyBindings(vm), since to their knowledge they'd like to apply the vm to their entire page.

### Problem

- This causes a conflict in knockout because one vm is being applied to the feedback form via the Site.master call, and one vm is being applied to the entire body by the page after it.

### Question

How can I enable these two things -- a modal dialog across all pages that uses knockout, and individual knockout pages -- to work in harmony?

## Demonstration of the Issue in (the Current) Code

Remember, the issue is that I want to be able to have one feedback VM that applies only to the feedback div across the client site, and I want to have other VMs able to be applied that aren't required to know anything about the feedback vm.

### Master Page file (Site.Master) -- Excerpt

This is on every page:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    &copy; <%=DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() %> Company, Inc. |  <a href="/">Home</a> | <a
        href="/about.aspx">About</a> | 

    <!-- begin feedback area -->

    <span id="FeedbackArea">
        <a data-bind="click: showModal">Feedback</a>

        <div id="feedback-modal" title="What's on your mind?">
            <div class="btn-group" id="feedbackButtonGroup">
                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: UpdateFeedbackType" style="padding-top: 6px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-warning fa-2x fa-align-center"></i>

                    <br />
                    <span>Problem</span>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: UpdateFeedbackType" style="padding-top: 6px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x fa-align-center"></i>

                    <br />
                    <span>Question</span>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: UpdateFeedbackType" style="padding-top: 6px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-2x fa-align-center"></i>

                    <br />
                    <span>Suggestion</span>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: UpdateFeedbackType" style="padding-top: 6px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x fa-align-center"></i>

                    <br />
                    <span>Praise</span>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: UpdateFeedbackType" style="padding-top: 6px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x fa-align-center"></i>

                    <br />
                    <span>General</span>

                </button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Enter feedback here" data-bind="value: feedbackText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button>Send Feedback</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button data-bind="click: CancelFeedback">Cancel</button>
            <h3>Other Information: </h3>

            <ul>
                <li><strong>Feedback Type:</strong> <span data-bind="text: feedbackType"></span></li>
                <li><strong>Current URL:</strong> <span data-bind="text: pageUserIsOn"></span></li>
                <li><strong>Current User: </strong><%=hdnLoggedInUsername.Value %></li>
                <li><strong>Current Client: </strong>[Not yet captured]</li>
                <li><strong>Current Tab: </strong>[Not yet captured]</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span>
    <!-- End feedback area --> 
</div>
```

### Feedback.JS -- This is also included in every page

...a somewhat-namespaced definition of a FeedbackVM:

```
var FeedbackNamespace = FeedbackNamespace || {};
```

..the definition of the namespace itself:

```
FeedbackNamespace = {
    ViewModel: function () {
       // etc. etc. 
    }
};
```

...and the declaration of a VM variable plus wiring it up on `document.ready()`:

```
var FeedbackVM;
$(document).ready(function () {
    FeedbackVM = new FeedbackNamespace.ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(FeedbackVM, $('#FeedbackArea')[0]); 
    FeedbackVM.Start();
    log('FeedbackVM started');
});
```

### Other Pages without Knockout / JS

Other pages may or may not have any javascript on them at all, let alone knockout. On these pages, the FeedbackVM currently works fine.

### Pages with their own Knockout ViewModel

These pages would have their own namespaced JS file with their own `document.ready()` event, that creates a vm of say `invoiceUploaderVM = new InvoiceUploader.ViewModel()`, and then calls `ko.applyBindings(invoiceUploaderVM)`.

This is where we run into trouble.

## Update: One potential Approach and a little trouble

In the Site.master page, I wrapped my entire footer in a "stopBindings: true" div:

```
<div data-bind="stopBindings: true">
    <div class="footer" id="footerDiv">
        <!-- Feedback Viewmodel stuff in here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've defined `stopBindings` as:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBindings = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

My Feedback.js file, loaded on every page as part of a global JS file, has:

```
var FeedbackNamespace = FeedbackNamespace || {};
FeedbackNamespace = {
    // defines viewmodel, etc. etc.
};
var FeedbackVM;
$(document).ready(function () {
    FeedbackVM = new FeedbackNamespace.ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(FeedbackVM, $('#footerDiv')[0]); 
    FeedbackVM.Start();
    log('FeedbackVM started');
});
```

This approach works perfectly well -- as long as there are no other viewmodels being bound. On the pages that inherit from my master page, I might have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    vm = new invoiceUploader.ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

I would expect that this:

- Sets up the feedback viewmodel applied to the div, stopping other viewmodels
- Sets up the invoiceUploader viewmodel and applies it to the body (which is then stopped by the stopBindings div)

However, instead I get an error upon loading the child page along the lines of:

[image]

Commenting the line to apply the feedback bindings makes this work just fine again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your issue with not find the bindings for "click: function() { return ToggleHelp }" is due to a scoping issue. You will want to change the binding string so it's simply "click: ToggleHelp". Or get the data from the callback data passed in by knockoutjs. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I would put the view model for your modal in a global object and do whatever you need to do with it **aside from applying the bindings** in a shared script:

```
window.feedbackModal = {
    foo: ko.observable("Whatever you need to do here"),
    bar: ko.observable("assuming it can be done the same on every page")
};
```

Then in the Site.master

```
<div class="feedback-modal" data-bind="with: feedbackModal">
  <p data-bind="text: foo"></p>
  <p data-bind="text: bar"></p>
</div>
```

And in every individual page's script:

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.individualProperty = ko.observable(true);
  this.specificAction = function() { /* do something specific to this page */ };

  this.feedbackModal = window.feedbackModal;
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

So window.feedbackModal could be undefined and it won't cause you problems, but if you `ko.applyBindings`, you have to have a `feedbackModal` property exposed in the view model or you'll get errors applying those bindings.

Of course, there are more clever ways you could implement this basic idea in order to fit your patterns the best, but the big point is, as you know, you can't apply bindings twice, so you need to defer that task to your most specific code and expose your reusable code to to it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for jumping in! A quick question: what happens in this case when I have a child page that has no knockout script of its own whatsoever? Then there would be nothing to apply the feedback modal, or I'd have to add this script on every page (what I'm looking to avoid). I'll try to add some code to illustrate what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: If you never run `ko.applyBindings`, you'll never have errors because of your `data-bind` attributes. In short, the scenario you're asking about is a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another strategy for separation of common modules from page dependant modules:

```
// An example of a module that runs on everypage
var modalDialog = function(){
    this.name = "dialog1";
    this.title = ko.observable("My Modal Title");
    this.content = ko.observable("My Modal content is also something");
}
// An example of a module that runs on everypage
var modalDialog2 = function(){
    this.name = "dialog2";
    this.title = ko.observable("My Modal Title 2");
    this.content = ko.observable("My Modal content is also something 2");
}
// Either generate it automatically or by hand
// to represent which modules are common
var commonModules = [modalDialog, modalDialog2];

// An example of a module only for this page
var pageModule = function(){
    this.pageFunction = function(){
        alert("Called page function");
    }
}

// Composition is the final object you will actually bind to the page
var composition = {
    pageMod: new pageModule()
}

// Let's add the common modules to the composition 
ko.utils.arrayForEach(commonModules, function(item){
    var module = new item();
    composition[module.name] = module;
});

// Bind the composition
ko.applyBindings(composition);
```

example HTML for this would be:

```
<div class="modalDialog">
    <h2 data-bind="text: dialog1.title"><h2>
    <h2 data-bind="text: dialog1.content"><h2>
</div>
<div class="modalDialog">
    <h2 data-bind="text: dialog2.title"><h2>
    <h2 data-bind="text: dialog2.content"><h2>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h2>Welcome to page</h2>
    <div id="somePageStuff">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: pageMod.pageFunction">Click me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Link to the jsfille for this](http://jsfiddle.net/9a5Tx/12/)

Comment: Hi XGreen, thanks for jumping in! normally i'd be fine with this, except that I only have some other pages that even have knockout, while the feedback script and its bindings are in completely separate files. Given this, I don't see a way I could use your approach without specifying a composition on every page (even pages that used no knockout of their own at all). Could you elaborate? I'll try to add some code as well to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up by using a technique to not have scope your bindings to a specific area in your page.

Check out: [How to stop knockout.js bindings evaluating on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254632/how-to-stop-knockout-js-bindings-evaluating-on-child-elements)

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/anAgent/RfM2R/

HTML

```
<div id="Main">
    <label data-bind="text: ViewModel.Name">default</label>
    <div data-bind="stopBindings: true">
        <div id="ChildBinding">
            <label data-bind="text: AnotherViewModel.Name">default</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.stopBindings = {
        init: function () {
            return {
                controlsDescendantBindings: true
            };
        }
    };
    var data = {
        ViewModel: {
            Name: "Testing"
        }
    };

    var data2 = {
        AnotherViewModel: {
            Name: "More Testing"
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(data, $("#Main")[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(data2, $("#MyModalHtml")[0]);

});
```

Comment: hi anAgent, thanks for jumping in! A little confused as to your solution. I don't necessarily want to stop knockout from processing the bindings (which is what stopBindings appears to do in my app). I'd like the feedback modal to be bound, while also allowing other pages to apply their bindings without needing to be aware of the feedback viewModel and its bindings even existing. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Hi Sean, what I was trying to point out is that you can have two View Models bound to your DOM - allowing you to work with the modal independently from you main view model. Knockoutjs will not allow to "apply bindings" twice. The stopBindings stops the first "applyBindings" from doing any events - thus allowing you to bind a modal with a different view model.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I ran into an issue: applying stopBindinga to my modal container div causes both viewmodels to stop working. Any idea what I could be doing wrong offhand as I research it?

Comment: I've updated the question to include an entire section where I attempt to apply this solution but am having some trouble. Hoping you might notice what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!