# Is it possible to pause initial Knockout evaluation of an attribute, until a user changes the associated observable?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm working on a website feature which allows a user to make live changes (like size and URL) to an embedded YouTube video using knockout.js. The page initially loads an iframe with both hard-coded attribute defaults and data bindings, **but it is not binded yet**.

```
<iframe data-bind="attr: {src: videoUrl() }, style: {width: width() + 'px', height: height() + 'px', }" style="width: 420px; height: 315px;" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/OvxlHa6yjqM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Bindings are applied to the iframe after some user interaction** - let's say a 'Show Options' button click.

```
$('some_button').click(function() { ko.applyBindings(viewModel) });
```

The view model contains the video options.

```
var viewModel = {
    width: ko.observable(420),
    height: ko.observable(315),
    videoId: ko.observable('OvxlHa6yjqM')
}
```

The iframe src is a computed observable.

```
viewModel.videoUrl = this.ko.computed( function () {
    return 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.videoId();
}, viewModel );
```

As soon as `ko.applyBindings()` is executed knockout.js evaluates all binded observables and outputs them in the HTML, even if they are the same as the hard-coded ones. Attributes like width and height re-render instantly, but the `videoUrl` computed observable which controls the `src` attribute causes the iframe to rerender and flicker for a second, even though its `src`  is unchanged. If the user enter a new `videoId` the iframe will flicker and re-render with the new video, which is perfectly normal. But **is there a way to prevent/pause initial evaluation of the `videoUrl` until it is actually changed** to something else via entering a new `videoId` for example?

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/datanasov/gfy0jnw4/)

I've tried the `deferEvaluation` computed option, but it doesn't work for me (perchance its purpose is different). I've tried some conditional bindingHandlers, but can't seem to figure out the proper logic.

### Update

Knockout.js is not loaded in the document where the initial iframe is loaded. It is loaded in the options container which happens to be a separate iframe. This means that knockout only loads and applies bindings to the iframe in the parent document after the user brings up the options (clicks the button).

**The view model is applied separately to the options list and the iframe container because of this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find one *magic solution*, but after all my question is quite specific. I was able to figure out a few methods on how to solve this.

#### Method 1: Apply bindings after first change

Since the ViewModel is applied separately to the options list and the iframe the most simple solution would be to apply it only to the options list at first and apply it to the iframe only after any of the options are changed. This way the iframe will not flicker on entering edit mode, but will flicker on any first change - even if that is a change to the size.

#### Method 2: Prevent initial iframe src binding

I found a nice technique here: [How to stop knockout.js bindings evaluating on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9254632/2156986)

Using a `stopBindings: true` (read the discussion above) binding on the element parent to the iframe I am able to apply bindings normally and ignore only the iframe itself. Now I can detect a change to the video src (video id) via `viewModel.videoId.subscribe( function () {})` and check if this is an initial change via `ko.computedContext.isInitial()`. The I can set the `stopBindings` to false. The downside is that now in order to monitor for changes to the src I need to restart the bindings with `ko.cleanNode(element)` and then again `ko.applyBindings`. But this works and now the video flickers only after a change to the src which is idea.

#### Method 3: Two ViewModels

I haven't even begun to explore this solution, but it basically involves having a separate viewmodel for the `videoId` which will be applied after a change is made - like the above solution. This will prevent re-binding, but I think is quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to call `applyBindings` immediately when the DOM loads, and only show/hide the options upon button click.

First, remove the explicit `src` attribute and let Knockout set the attribute upon binding:

```
<iframe data-bind="attr: {src: videoUrl() }, style: {width: width() + 'px', height: height() + 'px', }" style="width: 420px; height: 315px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then move the `applyBinding` call outside of the click handler:

```
$('bind').addEvent('click', function () {
    this.hide();
    $('options').show();
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfy0jnw4/8/)

Comment: This is a perfectly accurate answer. However, I forgot to mention a very important thing: the page with the initial iframe doesn't load knockout.js. It is only loaded in the video options container which is a separate iframe. So applyBindings can first be called when the so-called options container is brought up. It then applies the view model to the iframe in the parent. I will update the question immediately.